# Is Solace VMR for HP-Unix available ? and do we have C-API for HP-Unix?

Tags: solace

I would like to know below details regarding Solace. Could you please help me!

All of my client code is present in C and built in HP-Unix machine.
Now with this client I would like to push the messages to Solace. I wanted to test this in my local environment.

So, I want to know, does Solace support HP-Unix? Do we have a VMR to install in HP-Unix and C-API for HP-Unix 64 bit? I did not find one from solace website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have a VMR to install in HP-Unix

No.
Note that the Solace Virtual Message Router is a Virtual Machine/docker image that requires an hypervisor or an system running docker.

The complete list of platforms can be found at:
http://dev.solace.com/downloads/#vmr

> Do we have C-API for HP-Unix 64 bit?

Unfortunately, no.
The supported environments for the C API are:

- Linux26-i386, GCC
- Linux26/Linux31-x86_64, GCC
- SunOS10-i386 (32-bit), GCC
- SunOS10-x86 (64-bit), GCC
- SunOS10-sparc (32-bit and 64-bit versions), GCC
- Windows Server 2008 operating system (32-bit and 64-bit versions), Microsoft 
  Visual Studio 2005 and later
- Windows Server 2012 operating system, Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and later
- Windows 7 operating system (32-bit and 64-bit versions), Microsoft 
  Visual Studio 2005 and later
- Windows 8 operating system (32-bit and 64-bit versions), Microsoft 
  Visual Studio 2005 and later
- iOS 7, GCC, (ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64, i386, x86_x64)
- iOS 8, GCC, (ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64, i386, x86_x64)
- AIX 6 PowerPC (64-bit), GCC
- OS X Darwin13 x86_64, GCC
- Ubuntu Linux319 PowerPC (Little Endian), GCC
- SUSE Linux30 PowerPC (Big Endian), GCC
- HP OpenVMS 8.4-2 and later versions of the OS, running on 64-bit Itanium processors
- IBM S390, Linux/GCC/TPF